# Copying an object from a specific index to another arrayList (Java)

Tags: java, oop, arraylist, collections

I am creating an app in Java for booking lessons. Lessons are objects and stored in an arrayList called mathsList. When a lesson is booked I need to copy the lesson and add it to a student record which is stored in another arrayList called luisCortesStudentRecord.

What is the best way of achieving this? For example if I wanted to copy and add the object at index(0) to luisCortesStudentRecord.
So far I have only seen examples relating to copying the whole arrayList. Please my main method below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Lesson maths1 = new Lesson("Maths", "Wednesday", "01.07.2020", "8:00", "Cristina Espinoza", false);
        Lesson maths2 = new Lesson("Maths", "Wednesday", "08.07.2020", "10:00", "Cristina Espinoza", false);
        Lesson maths3 = new Lesson("Maths", "Wednesday", "15.07.2020", "10:00", "Marvin Dashford", false);
        Lesson maths4 = new Lesson("Maths", "Thursday", "22.07.2020", "15:00", "Cristina Espinoza", false);

        ArrayList<Lesson> mathsList = new ArrayList<Lesson>();
        ArrayList<Lesson> luisCortesStudentRecord = new ArrayList<Lesson>();

      
        mathsList.add(maths1);
        mathsList.add(maths2);
        mathsList.add(maths3);
        mathsList.add(maths4);


        Lesson temp = new Lesson();
        temp.booking(mathsList);

        temp.editBooking(mathsList);

    }
}
```

Comment: Use the `ArrayList.get(...)` method.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList has the method `get`, which returns the object at the index given as parameter. For example:

```
Lesson marvin = mathsList.get(2);
```

This is a reference to the same object `maths3`. You can add this to another ArrayList as you please. Keep in mind, though, that if you were to change some fields of `marvin`, the same fields would change in `maths3` (because it is the same object).

Comment: Hi thanks for getting back to me. Sorry I am a beginner so please bear with me. I take it this pieve of code would be placed in the lesson class rather than the main  - Lesson marvin = mathsList.get(2) ?

Comment: Just a little confused on how this would be added to the new arrayList.

Comment: You can add it to the new arrayList just as you added it to the old one:
`luisCortes.add(marvin);`

If you're a total beginner, stumbling around and trying to ask the right questions on StackOverflow might not be the best course of action. A better way to learn could be some of the numerous free online courses, such as the one by University of Helsinki at https://java-programming.mooc.fi/. Oftentimes they have more immediate feedback to help you forward

Comment: That's great.  I've had a play around and can see how your example works. You'll notice in the Lesson (maths) objects there is a boolean. This Boolean is true if the lesson is booked or false if the lesson is available, Is there a way of adding the lesson to another array list once the boolean is amended to true after the lesson has been booked?

Comment: @KevinJervis it sure is possible, though what you should do depends on the context and what you want. In this case, I'd probably make a method `makeTrue(List addTo, Lesson lesson)`
It's simple to do it without, but if you do it this way, the behaviour is the same everywhere you try to do it, not subject to typos or something else.